# Requests coming back as 401 unauthorized

Tags: spring, spring-security, http-status-code-401

I recently asked a question very similar to this one but instead of 401 the error I was getting was 403 (Forbbiden), but I changed the entire code so I decided to post a new one specific to this code and this problem.

I'm trying to create an user logic to my project (for the first time ever) but it has been impossible to implement any kind of security measure. I've been stuck in this for days so if anyone knows where I'm wrong I'd be grateful!

this is my code:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/users/create", "/users/create/**").permitAll()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

```java
@Data
@Component
public class CreateUserRoleDTO {
    private Integer idUser;
    
    private List<Integer> idsRoles;

    public CreateUserRoleDTO() {
        super();
    }
    
    public CreateUserRoleDTO(Integer idUser, List<Integer> idsRoles) {
        super();
        this.idUser = idUser;
        this.idsRoles = idsRoles;
    }

    public Integer getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }

    public void setIdUser(Integer idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }

    public List<Integer> getIdsRoles() {
        return idsRoles;
    }

    public void setIdsRoles(List<Integer> idsRoles) {
        this.idsRoles = idsRoles;
    }       
}
```

```java
@Service
public class CreateRoleUserService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;

    @Autowired
    private CreateUserRoleDTO createUserRoleDTO;
    
    public Users execute(CreateUserRoleDTO createUserRoleDTO) {
        Optional<Users> userExists=repo.findById(createUserRoleDTO.getIdUser());
        List<Roles> roles=new ArrayList<>();
        
        if (userExists.isEmpty()) {
            throw new Error("User does not exist");
        }
        roles=createUserRoleDTO.getIdsRoles().stream().map(role -> {
            return new Roles(role);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        Users user=userExists.get();
        user.setRole(roles);
        
        repo.save(user);
        return user;    
    }
```

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name="users_table")
    public class Users implements Serializable{
        
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Integer id;
        
        @Column(unique=true)
        private String login;
        
        @Column(unique=true)
        private String email; 
        
        private String password;
        
        @ManyToMany
        private List<Roles> role; 
        
    }
```

(plus the getters and setters and constructors)

`data.sql`:

```
INSERT INTO `ROLES`(`ID`, `NAME`) VALUES(1, 'USER');
INSERT INTO `ROLES`(`ID`,`NAME`) VALUES(2, 'ADMIN');
```

-> the code runs fine, it even gives me the security password, the problem appears when I try to make **any** kind of requests.

The entire code if I've left anything out: https://github.com/vitoriaacarvalho/backend-challenge-very-useful-tools-to-remember-

Comment: Can you add some more details, which endpoint you are trying to hit and what is the error you are getting which is an issue for you. Based on above set up /users/create or /users/create/** is the only allowed path and everything should be authenticated?

Comment: hiii! I'm trying to access "/users/create' (the one that should be allowed) and it returns me 401! @Neeraj

Comment: could you pleaase enable spring security debug logs and post your log output here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An authentication configuration is missing in your `SecurityConfig`. For example, try adding the following to your `configure` method:

```java
http.httpBasic();
```

Additionally, your security configuration is missing a default authorization rule, so authentication is not actually required. You can try adding `.anyRequest().authenticated()` to test this out.

Here's a configuration which uses the lambda syntax available in the DSL and is ready to be upgraded to Spring Security 6:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .antMatchers("/users/create", "/users/create/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        // Disable CSRF for testing.
        // TODO: Delete the following line and learn about CSRF!
        http.csrf().disable();

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean // Automatically injected into Spring Security
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    // Note: We don't configure a UserDetailsService since it is already 
    // annotated @Service and therefore already published as an @Bean.

}
```

Unfortunately, I also spotted a few other mistakes in your application that made it not work.

It looks like you have a mistake in the JPQL used to query the user for the `UserDetailsService`. The WHERE clause should be `where u.login = :username` (add a `u.`).

You also have the if-statement inverted as well. When throwing a `UsernameNotFoundException` (a better exception than `Error` for this case), it would look like:

```java
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Users user = repo.findByUsernameFetchRoles(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User does not exist!");
        }

        return UserPrincipal.create(user);
    }
```

Lastly, the constructor of your `Users` class was not assigning user data from the `user` parameter. It should be:

```
    public UserPrincipal(Users user) {
        this.login = user.getLogin();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        ...
    }
```

With those changes, authentication works and you're on your way to learning Spring Security!

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! I was only able to solve the problem yesterday and it was because of a very very stupid thing but you helped me very much either way!